# when should groupByKey API used in spark programming?

Tags: apache-spark

GroupByKey suffers from shuffling the data.And GroupByKey functionality can be achieved either by using combineByKey or reduceByKey.So When should this API be used ? Is there any use case ?

Comment: It is odd in that it is an API. Good question.

Comment: @thebluephantom I got the answer long ago. I have posted as answer below.

Comment: Did not think you had answered question! I agree, otherwise why have it as API. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link below, GroupByKey should be avoided.

[Avoid GroupByKey](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html)

Comment: I wouldn't say *"avoid it"*, but *"prefer more specialized transformations when possible"* :).

Comment: `groupByKey` is different than `reduceByKey` you cannot always sub one for the other.  I guess if you can use `reduceByKey` you should.  That article is a little dated.  Things seem to be changing fast with Spark (performance improvements).

Answer (score 3):

Combine and reduce will also eventually shuffle, but they have better memory and speed performance characteristics because they are able to do more work to reduce the volume of data *before* the shuffle.

Consider if you had to sum a numeric attribute by a group RDD[(group, num)]. `groupByKey` will give you RDD[(group, List[num])] which you can then manually reduce using `map`. The shuffle would need to move all the individual `num`s to the destination partitions/nodes to get that list - many rows being shuffled.

Because `reduceByKey` knows that what you are doing with the `num`s (ie. summing them), it can sum each individual partition before the shuffle - so you'd have at most one row per `group` being written out to shuffle partition/node.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid GroupByKey when the data in the merge field will be reduced to single value . Eg. In case of sum for a particular key.

Use `GroupByKey` when you know that merge field is not going to be reduced to single value. `Eg: List reduce(_++_)` --> Avoid this.

The reason being reduce a list will create memory both map side and reduce side. Memory that is created on executor that doesn't own the key will be wasted during shuffle.
Good example would be TopN.

More on this -
https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey

Answer (score 0):

I woud say if groupByKey is last transformation in your chain of work (or you do anything after that has narrow dependency only), they you may consider it.

The reason reducebyKey is preferred is
1. Combine as alister mentioned above
2. ReduceByKey also partitions the data so that sum/agg becomes narrow ie can happen within partitions