# Spark: How to manage a big aggregateByKey on a single machine

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Scala and Spark to manage a big quantity of records and each of those records has the form:

```
single record => (String, Row)
```

and every `Row` is composed by 45 different kind of values (`String`, `Integer`, `Long`).

To aggregate them I am using:

```
myRecords.aggregateByKey ( List [Any]( ) ) (
      (aggr, value) => aggr ::: (value :: Nil),
      (aggr1, aggr2) => aggr1 ::: aggr2
)
```

The problem is that I am getting constanly the message:

```
15/11/21 17:54:14 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor driver with no recent heartbeats: 147767 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms

15/11/21 17:54:14 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor driver on localhost: Executor heartbeat timed out after 147767 ms

[Stage 3:====>               (875 + 24) / 3252]

15/11/21 17:57:10 WARN BlockManager: Putting block rdd_14_876 failed

...and finally...

15/11/21 18:00:27 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 876.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 5465)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

What I can guess is that the aggregate is so big that to match the key for a new record it will require more and more time, till a task gets to some timeout because it didn't find the right place where add the record's value.

I played with different parameters from `spark-submit` like:

```
spark.default.parallelism => to reduce the size of tasks augmenting this value

spark.executor.memory => usually I put much less then driver memory

spark.driver.memory => the whole driver memory (single machine tho)

--master local[number of cores]
```

Any idea how to get at the end of the process without out-of-memory/timeouts?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to merge two csv files based on:

1) join them based on a csv column
2) merge the join rows, based on 3 column values
3) aggregate/group this joined & merged files with the key at 2)
4) doing some stuff on the single aggregate data from 3)

This is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame, Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object MyRecords {

  def createKey(k1: String, k2: String, k3: String):String = {
    Seq(k1, k2, k3).iterator.map ( r => if (r == null) "" else r.trim.toUpperCase ).mkString ("")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val df1FilePath = args ( 0 )
    val df2FilePath = args ( 1 )

    val sc = new SparkContext ( new SparkConf ( ) )
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext ( sc )
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val df1 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").load(df1FilePath).as("one")

    df1.registerTempTable("df1")

    val df2 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").load(df2FilePath)

    val df2Renamed = df2.select(
      col ( "v0" ).as ( "y_v0" ),
      col ( "v1" ).as ( "y_v1" ),
      col ( "v2" ).as ( "y_v2" ),
      col ( "v3" ).as ( "y_v3" ),
      col ( "v4" ).as ( "y_v4" ),
      col ( "v5" ).as ( "y_v5" ),
      col ( "v6" ).as ( "y_v6" ),
      col ( "v7" ).as ( "y_v7" ),
      col ( "v8" ).as ( "y_v8" ),
      col ( "v9" ).as ( "y_v9" ),
      col ( "v10" ).as ( "y_v10" ),
      col ( "v11" ).as ( "y_v11" ),
      col ( "v12" ).as ( "y_v12" ),
      col ( "v13" ).as ( "y_v13" ),
      col ( "v14" ).as ( "y_v14" ),
      col ( "v15" ).as ( "y_15" ),
      col ( "v16" ).as ( "y_16" ),
      col ( "v17" ).as ( "y_17" ),
      col ( "v18" ).as ( "y_18" ),
      col ( "v19" ).as ( "y_19" ),
      col ( "v20" ).as ( "y_20" ),
      col ( "v21" ).as ( "y_21" ),
      col ( "v22" ).as ( "y_22" ),
      col ( "v23" ).as ( "y_23" ),
      col ( "v24" ).as ( "y_24" ),
      col ( "v25" ).as ( "y_25" ),
      col ( "v26" ).as ( "y_26" ),
      col ( "v27" ).as ( "y_27" ),
      col ( "v28" ).as ( "y_28" ),
      col ( "v29" ).as ( "y_29" ),
      col ( "v30" ).as ( "y_30" ),
      col ( "v31" ).as ( "y_31" ),
      col ( "v32" ).as ( "y_32" )
    ).as("two")

    df2Renamed.registerTempTable("df2")

    val dfJoined = dfArchive.join( df2Renamed, $"one.v0" === $"two.y_v0", "fullouter" ).as("j")

    dfJoined.registerTempTable("joined")

    val dfMerged = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM joined").map(r =>
      if (r.getAs("y_v1") != null) {
        (createKey (r.getAs("y_v2"), r.getAs("y_v3"), r.getAs("y_v4") ), r)
      } else {
        (createKey (r.getAs("v2"), r.getAs("v3"), r.getAs("v4") ), r)
      })

    dfMerged.groupByKey().collect().foreach(println)

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show ``Row`` a bit more? And ``myRecords``? I think your aggregation can be made more efficient

Answer (score 2):

Since all you do here is grouping by key it is better to use `groupByKey` instead of `aggregateByKey`, especially a one which creates a huge number of temporary objects like `value :: Nil` (why not simply `value :: aggr`?).

Since it doesn't perform map side aggregations it should put less stress on a garbage collector (see [SPARK-772](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-772)).

See also: [Is groupByKey ever preferred over reduceByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33221713/1560062)

**Edit**:

Regarding code you've provided in the update it doesn't really make sense. If you want to use `DataFrames` there is no reason to group data using `RDDs` in the first place. Also you duplicate your data by keeping both `Strings` and casted values increasing memory usage and additionally stressing GC. It looks like what you need is roughly something like this (with a small help of [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)):

```
// Load data, optionally add .option("inferSchema", "true")
val df1 = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "\t")
    .load(file1Path)

val df2 = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "\t")
    .load(file2Path)

// Join and cache
val df = df1.join(
  df2,
  // Join condition
  df1("foo") === df2("foo") &&
    df1("bar") === df2("bar") &&
    df1("baz") === df2("baz"),
  "fullouter")
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.cacheTable("df")

// Perform all the required casting using safe cast methods
// and replace existing columns
df.withColumn("some_column", $"some_column".cast(IntegerType))
```

Any aggregations you need you can perform you can execute on a data frame [without physically grouping the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32903568/1560062). If you want to subset simply use `where` or `filter`.

Comment: I already expected to see you here ;)  Your answers are high quality.

Comment: same issue: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)`

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` and `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at ...` are not the same issues. Actually why do you convert this data to rows and group in the first place? Or collect for that matter.

Comment: @zero323 I cannot see how to do differently. I merge two rows from two files in a new array. I think that is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer first. One file has ~ 100,000,000 and the other ~ 30,000,000 records. One machine only with memory drive = 80g and memory executor = 12g and 24 cores cpu. Following your answer, will I run the `mergedFiles` inside the `foreach` after the `groupByKey` as final transformation?

Comment: I have semplified a lot the code now, using spark-sql/csv as you suggested but I am still getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit` during the `groupByKey` stage. This is the configuration: spark-submit --name "my records" --master local[4] --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0 --conf "spark.local.dir=/opt/spark-tmp/" --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0 --conf spark.executor.memory=12g --conf spark.driver.memory=80g target/scala-2.11/er-archive_2.11-0.0.1.jar /opt/files/file1.txt /opt/files/file2.txt. The total memory of the machine is 96g. Any idea?

Comment: Like I've already said - use `filter` / `where` and SQL aggregates not `groupBy`. Regarding error you see right now it is most likely a problem with JVM configuration and has been covered multiple times on SO.

Comment: can you please show where/how you mean to use filter/where? I can trying to figure out a simple way to replace groupBy separating by the same indexes. Is that more memory efficient?

Comment: If I understood what you meant, for example, with a list of names that of course start with letter A to Z, I could split the big aggregate in 26 parts as in the alphabet letters, filtering the data, so I will get 26 smaller chunk of data to group by?