# How can I use reduceByKey instead of GroupByKey to construct a list?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

My RDD is made of many items, each of which is a tuple as follows:

```
(key1, (val1_key1, val2_key1))
(key2, (val1_key2, val2_key2))
(key1, (val1_again_key1, val2_again_key1))
... and so on
```

I used GroupByKey on the RDD which gave the result as

```
(key1, [(val1_key1, val2_key1), (val1_again_key1, val2_again_key1), (), ... ()])
(key2, [(val1_key2, val2_key2), (), () ... ())])
... and so on
```

I need to do the same using reduceByKey. I tried doing

```
RDD.reduceByKey(lambda val1, val2: list(val1).append(val2))
```

but it doesn't work.

Please suggest the right way to implement using reduceByKey()

Comment: This should work...but it starts as a list, so I think you just need to remove the list wrapper....`val1.append(val2)`

Comment: @JustinPihony I just tried this but it throws "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'" may be because the first element is starts to work with is not a list

Comment: a) You cannot (in a non-hacky-way) do __the same__ because types on LHS and RHS don't match. b) It is significantly less efficient because it __doesn't reduce anything__. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/33221713/1560062

Comment: Ahh, I don't know my python types well enough...I thought you already had a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is you cannot (or at least not in a straightforward and Pythonic way without abusing language dynamism). Since values type and return type are different (a list of tuples vs a single tuple) `reduce` is not a valid function here. You could use `combineByKey` or `aggregateByKey` for example like this:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([
    ("key1", ("val1_key1", "val2_key1")),
    ("key2", ("val1_key2", "val2_key2"))])

rdd.aggregateByKey([], lambda acc, x: acc + [x], lambda acc1, acc2: acc1 + acc2)
```

but it is just a less efficient version of `groupByKey`. See also [Is groupByKey ever preferred over reduceByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33221713/1560062)

Comment: Wouldn't using aggregateByKey in this case prevent the keys from being shuffled across the network? Meaning that the function would run for whatever keys it has on whatever node it is on without worrying about the existence of keys on other nodes.

Comment: @Salmonerd Actually, I've looked at the PySpark code and it doesn't disable map side aggregation yet. So this is (with some small differences) equivalent to `groupByKey`. In general there is another problem. If number of unique keys per partition is low it can be beneficial to perform map-side aggregation. But in general is expensive since it has to create large amount of temporary objects. This is a slow process and these objects have to be garbage collected later.

Comment: Thanks for the additional  clarification. Do you know if using the Scala version would have any performance gains over pySpark or would offer a better solution?

Comment: I would expect anything spectacular. While it can be slightly faster most of the job is probably serialization, transfer and serialization.