# python spark reducebykey forming a single list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have two lines as below and they produced the attached output. The output is correct. But in the case of the second statement, I want to form a single tuple and not a tuple of tuples. How could i achieve the same?

```
print ratingsRDD.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[2])).take(5)
print ratingsRDD.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[2])).reduceByKey(lambda p,q: (p,q)).take(4)


[(1, 5.0), (1, 3.0), (1, 5.0), (1, 5.0), (1, 4.0)]
[(2, ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((4.0, 3.0), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 5.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 4.0), 5.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 2.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 5.0), 1.0), 3.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 4.0), 5.0), 2.0), 3.0), 2.0), 1.0), ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((5.0, 4.0), 4.0), 5.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 2.0), 3.0), 3.0), 2.0), 2.0), 4.0), 5.0), 5.0), 2.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 2.0), 5.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 2.0), 5.0), 4.0), 5.0), 2.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0), 2.0), 5.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 5.0))), (4, ((((((((((3.0, 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 5.0), 5.0), 5.0), ((((((((((5.0, 4.0), 4.0), 5.0), 2.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 1.0), 5.0), 5.0))), (6, ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((5.0, 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 4.0), 5.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 5.0), 5.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((4.0, 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 2.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 1.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0))), (8, ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((3.0, 5.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 2.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 5.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 5.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 2.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 2.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 4.0), ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((3.0, 3.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 2.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 4.0), 5.0), 3.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0), 5.0), 3.0), 2.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), 5.0), 5.0), 3.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 4.0), 5.0), 4.0), 4.0), 2.0), 4.0), 3.0), 4.0), 5.0), 5.0), 5.0), 3.0), 2.0), 5.0), 4.0), 5.0), 3.0), 5.0), 5.0), 4.0), 3.0)))]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `groupByKey`. There is no good reason to use `reduceByKey` here:

```
grouped = sc.parallelize(
    [(1, 5.0), (1, 3.0), (1, 5.0), (1, 5.0), (1, 4.0)]
).groupByKey()

grouped.mapValues(list).first()
## (1, [5.0, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.0])
```

Just for the record, what you have is a `tuple` of `tuples` not a `list` of `lists`.

If you really want a solution which doesn't require `groupByKey` see [How can I use reduceByKey instead of GroupByKey to construct a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34293261/1560062).

Comment: can we stick to reducebykey? i read online that groupbykey is not an efficient option. Thanks for informing about tuple of tuples. I will update my question

Comment: It's not that bad if you aren't dealing with a ton of data. I believe it calls the same underlying functions, and, since you really do want to group things, it's probably fine.

Comment: @user2543622 Let me ask you a question (evil grin here). Do you remember why `groupByKey` should be avoided (I am pretty sure [this is what you mean](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) by _read online_)? And a follow-up question is how `reduceByKey` with `[]` or `()` can help you? (Hint: it cannot...)

Comment: @ChrisChambers I would even go further - if you need the result of `groupByKey` you cannot do better than `groupByKey`.