# ways to replace groupByKey in apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, transformation

I would like to know best way to replace **groupByKey** operation with another.

Basically I would like to obtain an **RDD[(int,List[Measure])**, my situation:

```
// consider measures like RDD of objects
measures.keyBy(_.getId)
        .groupByKey
```

My idea is to use **reduceByKey** instead, bacause it cause less shuffle:

```
measures.keyBy(_.getId)
        .mapValues(List(_))
        .reduceByKey(_++_)
```

But I think is very inefficient cause it force me to instantiate a tons of unnecessary List objects.

**Can anyone have others idea to replace groupByKey?**

Comment: Have you tried and measure it, to see if it is actually (more) inefficient for your use case? That's the only way to see if what you think is true for your data.

Comment: Beside that, other ways to replace groupByKey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is using `aggregateByKey`, which is specifically for combining values into a type different from the original values:

```
measures.keyBy(_.getId)
        .aggregateByKey(List[Measure]())(_ :+ _, _ ++ _)
```

This creates an empty list for each key in each partition, appends all values to these in each partition, then finally shuffles the lists to concatenate all for each key.

Appending to a list in Scala is O(n), it is better to prepend, which is O(1), but looks a bit less clean:

```
measures.keyBy(_.getId)
        .aggregateByKey(List[Measure]())(_.+:(_), _ ++ _)
```

or:

```
measures.keyBy(_.getId)
        .aggregateByKey(List[Measure]())((l, v) => v +: l, _ ++ _)
```

This is probably more efficient than your `reduceByKey` example, but the situations where `reduceByKey` and `aggregateByKey` are far superior over `groupByKey` are where you can first make a large reduction in data size, and only shuffle the much smaller results around. In this case you don't have this reduction: the intermediate lists contain all the data you start out with, so you are still shuffling with your full data set when the per-partition lists are combined (this holds similarly for using `reduceByKey`).

Moreover, as zero323 pointed out, `groupByKey` is actually more efficient in this case because it knows it is building lists of all the data and can perform optimisations specifically for that:

- It disables map-side aggregation which prevents building a big hash map with all the data
- It uses a smart buffer (`CompactBuffer`), which reduces the amount of memory allocations significantly compared to building up immutable lists one by one.

Another situation where the difference between `groupByKey` and `reduceByKey` or `aggregateByKey` may be minimal is when the number of keys isn't much smaller than the number of values.

Comment: Actually it is significantly less efficient due to map side reduce. `groupByKey` specifically avoids this approach to reduce GC cost. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/33222398/1560062 Immutable buffer makes it even worse.

Comment: Thanks! Read a bit deeper into what `groupByKey` does underneath and edited my answer in accordance and hopefully closer to the truth.