# Inconsistent results in pyspark combineByKey (as opposed to groupByKey)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to group by key some rows in a RDD so I can perform more advanced operations with the rows within one group. Please note, I do not want to calculate merely some aggregate values. The rows are key-value pairs, where the key is a GUID and the value is a complex object.

As per pyspark documentation, I first tried to implement this with combineByKey as it is supposed be more performant than groupByKey. The list at the beginning is just for illustration, not my real data:

```
l = list(range(1000))
numbers = sc.parallelize(l)
rdd = numbers.map(lambda x: (x % 5, x))

def f_init(initial_value):
    return [initial_value]

def f_merge(current_merged, new_value):
    if current_merged is None:
        current_merged = []
    return current_merged.append(new_value)

def f_combine(merged1, merged2):
    if merged1 is None:
        merged1 = []
    if merged2 is None:
        merged2 = []
    return merged1 + merged2

combined_by_key = rdd.combineByKey(f_init, f_merge, f_combine)

c = combined_by_key.collectAsMap()
i = 0
for k, v in c.items():
    if v is None:
        print(i, k, 'value is None.')
    else:
        print(i, k, len(v))
    i += 1
```

The output of this is:

```
0 0 0
1 1 0
2 2 0
3 3 0
4 4 0
```

Which is not what I expected. The same logic but implemented with groupByKey returns a correct output:

```
grouped_by_key = rdd.groupByKey()
d = grouped_by_key.collectAsMap()
i = 0
for k, v in d.items():
    if v is None:
        print(i, k, 'value is None.')
    else:
        print(i, k, len(v))
    i += 1
```

Returns:

```
0 0 200
1 1 200
2 2 200
3 3 200
4 4 200
```

So unless I'm missing something, this is the case when groupByKey is preferred over reduceByKey or combineByKey (the topic of related discussion: [Is groupByKey ever preferred over reduceByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221713/is-groupbykey-ever-preferred-over-reducebykey)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the case when understanding basic APIs is preferred. In particular if you check `list.append` docstring:

```
?list.append
## Docstring: L.append(object) -> None -- append object to end
## Type:      method_descriptor
```

you'll see that like the other mutating methods in Python API it by convention doesn't return modified object. It means that `f_merge` always returns `None` and there is no accumulation whatsoever.

That being said for most of the problems there much more efficient solutions than `groupByKey` but rewriting it with `combineByKey` (or `aggregateByKey`) is never one of these.

Comment: Thanks. Now that the issue is resolved, I tested the performance of both alternatives and the one with combineByKey is somewhat faster (on a larger dataset it should be more dramatic difference). I guess the reason is because combineByKey and groupByKey work differently and there is no guarantee that groupByKey will make that optimization to use data locality during the merges: http://codingjunkie.net/spark-combine-by-key/.

Comment: There are two problems here. a) Scala specifically disables map side aggregation (I reckon this what you mean by _optimization to use data locality_) to improve performance by reducing GC time b) Python implementation is not equivalent to the one provided by Scala and is actually implemented via combineByKey.