# Should the DataFrame function groupBy be avoided?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This [link](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221713/is-groupbykey-ever-preferred-over-reducebykey) tell me that the Spark `groupByKey` is not to be used if there is a large number of keys, since Spark shuffles all the keys around. Does the same apply to the [`groupBy`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy) function as well? Or is this something different?

I'm asking this because I want to do what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878370/how-to-select-the-first-row-of-each-group) tries to do, but I have a very large number of keys. It should be possible to do this without shuffling all the data around by reducing on each node locally, but I can't find the PySpark way to do this (frankly, I find the documentation quite lacking).

Essentially, I am trying to do is:

```
# Non-working pseudocode
df.groupBy("A").reduce(lambda x,y: if (x.TotalValue > y.TotalValue) x else y)
```

However, the dataframe API does not offer a "reduce" option. I'm probably misunderstanding what exactly dataframe is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

A DataFrame `groupBy` followed by an `agg` will not move the data around unnecessarily, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32903568/7579547) for a good example. Hence, there is no need to avoid it.

When using the RDD API, the opposite is true. Here it is preferable to avoid `groupByKey` and use a `reducebyKey` or `combineByKey` where possible. Some situations, however, do require one to use `groupByKey`.

---

The normal way to do this type of operation with the DataFrame API is to use `groupBy` followed by an aggregation using `agg`. In your example case, you want to find the maximum value for a single column for each group, this can be achived by the `max` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

joined_df.groupBy("A").agg(F.max("TotalValue").alias("MaxValue"))
```

In addition to `max` there are a multitude of functions that can be used in combination with `agg`, see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData) for all operations.

Comment: The problem with aggregation is that it throws away all columns except A and MaxValue. I need to keep the original columns. Effectively, this is supposed to be a complex filtering operation.

Comment: @Thomas: `groupBy` with `agg` will not move any data unnecessarily, see for example the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902982/dataframe-dataset-groupby-behaviour-optimization). If you need to keep the other columns you could try creating a struct following the third alternative in the linked question answer (make sure that the column to use as comparator is the first on in the struct).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is pretty all over the place.

There has been a lot of optimization work for dataframes. Dataframes has additional information about the structure of your data, which helps with this. I often find that many people recommend dataframes over RDDs due to "increased optimization."

There is a lot of heavy wizardry behind the scenes.

I recommend that you try "groupBy" on both RDDs and dataframes on large datasets and compare the results. Sometimes, you may need to just do it.

Also, for performance improvements, I suggest fiddling (through trial and error) with:

1. the spark configurations [Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)
2. shuffle.partitions [Doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options)